# Do North American electrical appliances work in Dominican Republic and if not - what adapter is needed?

Tags: power, dominican-republic

Coming from Canada, do I need to bring any adapters so that I can recharge my small electronic devices (phones, tablets, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need any plug or voltage adapters. The Dominican Republic uses the same voltage as Canada, which is 110/120V and 60Hz and the same plug type

Answer (score 1):

The Dominican Republic, like most of the Caribbean, uses the same plugs and voltage as mainland North America.

Several plug-information websites mention that sockets that accept earthed plugs (with three prongs) are uncommon in the Dominican Republic. There are other sites that disagree with that, but if any or your chargers come with an earthed power cord, you'll want to bring an adapter for that, just in case.